# How many tokens can I send at a time when sending a notification from the server?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

- I know that there is a subscription system
- But I don't find a limit on the number of tokens sent to firebase
- There is a version of 1000 tokens at a time on the Internet

Just if, for example, I have 100,000 users, will firebase allow me to send 300 000 - 400 000 tokens along with the message

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation on [sending messages to multiple devices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-multiple-devices):

> The REST API and the Admin FCM APIs allow you to multicast a message to a list of device registration tokens. **You can specify up to 500 device registration tokens per invocation.**